# Is this correct way to show the loader before react scripts load?

Tags: reactjs

When a React app starts, the browser takes some time to load the script. As a result, the screen becomes white, and the user is left unaware of what's happening. So after a lot of research , i found this solution its working fine. Where i am adding some js in my  tag.Also i added loader html code and css in my index.html file.
So my question is, is this a good apporach?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/logo.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <style>
      .loader-main {
         display: flex;
         align-items: center;
         justify-content: center;
           width: 100%;
          height: 90vh;
}
    .loader {
  animation: rotate 1s infinite;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
      .loader:before,
.loader:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
.loader:before {
  animation: ball1 1s infinite;
  background-color: #4f56ed;
  box-shadow: 30px 0 0 #ff3d00;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}


.hideLoader {
  display: none !important;
}


    </style>
    <script>
 
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        var root = document.getElementById("root");
        const loader = document.querySelector('.loader-main');

        if (root) {
          var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutationsList) {
            for (var mutation of mutationsList) {
              if (mutation.target === root && mutation.addedNodes.length > 0) {
                loader.classList.add('hideLoader');
                observer.disconnect();
              }
            }
          });

          observer.observe(root, { childList: true });
        }
      });     
    
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div class="loader-main" >
    <span class="loader"></span>
  </div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```